# external monitor self-acting reset to mirrored monitors under 16.04

Tags: display-resolution

Hardware: Lenovo T420 with Nvidia NVS4200m

Issue 1:
When using an external monitor (Full-HD) I may set the resolution of the external monitor via Settings -> Display (don't know the exact spelling as I use german language) and deactivate the internal monitor of the notebook and everything is fine for about a minute. Then the monitor settings are changed automatically to the previous setup. And if I do nothing - the settings flip back after additional amount of time. (WTF!)

I actually use X.org free drivers for the NVIDIA GPU. I tried the latest stable NVIDIA drivers (nvidia-364) without success.

I guess it has got something to do with the hybrid graphics solution Intel/Nvidia...

/var/log/Xorg.0.log basically shows:

```
[133.422] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 1440x900
[   133.423] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1440x900@59.9 on LVDS2 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[   134.032] resize called 1440 900
[   134.199] (II) NOUVEAU(G0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 9065
[   134.200] (II) NOUVEAU(G0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[   134.200] (II) NOUVEAU(G0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[   134.200] (II) NOUVEAU(G0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   134.200] (II) NOUVEAU(G0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz eP)
[   134.200] (II) NOUVEAU(G0): Modeline "720x480"x0.0   27.00  720 736 798 858  480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[   134.200] (II) NOUVEAU(G0): Modeline "1280x720"x0.0   74.25  1280 1390 1430 1650  720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz e)
... etc
```

When deactivating internal monitor and changing settings furthermore the settings are kept until reboot or suspend.

Issue 2:
How can the external monitor be configured to power off after some minutes? The settings under "Screen" are without effect for external monitor.

Anyone any ideas to fix that?